# SQL MAX() больше одного значения

Tags: sql

Есть такой запрос:

```
    SELECT name, MAX(SkillsCount) 
    FROM (SELECT Users.name, Users.id, COUNT(Skills.SkillName) as SkillsCount
        FROM Users join Skills on Users.id == Skills.id
        GROUP BY Users.id)
```

Но, он выводит лишь одно значение, хотя есть несколько значений с одинаковым SkillsCount (5)

Comment: Максимум по определению возможен только один. Вы можете отсортировать выборку по `SkillsCount` и лимитировать нужным количеством строк.

Comment: Для этого существует `Group by`, Вынесите из подзапроса(или добавьте еще один) и получите то что хотие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
WITH counts AS (SELECT Users.name, Users.id, COUNT(Skills.SkillName) as SkillsCount
     FROM Users join Skills on Users.id == Skills.id
     GROUP BY Users.id)
SELECT name, SkillsCount
  FROM counts
  WHERE SkillsCount=(SELECT MAX(SkillsCount) FROM counts);
```

Но дабы получить достойную производительность на больших таблицах придётся повозиться.